# Google Maps API incomplete address

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way of submitting to Maps API the complete address of a place and retreiving it from the API?

I tried to POST to the Place API, but the address doesn't split in component. I have a valid canadian address "6825 Saint-Pierre O. Saint-Hyacinthe J2T 5G7", but the MAPS API returns only the "prefix" for the postal code. I need the complete postal code for shipping purpose.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: probably. have you tried the documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Comment: Yes I have read it all, there is no mention of how can I get the full postal address from the API when it returns only the prefix.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get the complete postal code?